# How do I pass navController parameter in this one?

Tags: kotlin, authentication, android-jetpack

I'm kinda new to jetpack compose kotlin.This is my login screen function which takes 2 parameters:

```
fun loginScreen(
        navController: NavController,
        onClick: (mobileNum: String, otp: String) -> Unit
    ) {
       //my_code
      }
```

This is my navhost function

```
composable(route = Screen.Loginscreen.route){loginScreen(navController = navController,onClick = {mobileNum, otp ->  })}
```

This is where I call the function. How do I pass the navController here??
class LoginScreenActivity:ComponentActivity() {

```
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContent {
        Surface(color = MaterialTheme.colors.background) {
            loginScreen {

                mobileNum, otp ->
                if (mobileNum.isNotEmpty()) {
                    send(mobileNum)
                }

            }
```

//rest of the code

Let me know if I need to elaborate further.TIA

Answer (score 0):

To pass the argument in NavController, you need to pass in this way
`findNavController().navigate(directions)`

Also the direction contains the `SourceFragmentDirectionToDestionationFragment`